# Frontier on Docker - huge data file

Tags: ethereum

I've got Docker running on a Fedora Core VM and attempted to run a Frontier node like this:

```
$ sudo docker run -it -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go
```

which promptly fired up and started synchronizing the blockchain.  it filled up my disk, so I added 40G more and it filled that up too.  the space is being taken up by `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data`.

how much space do I need??? or is there a problem?